# import CSV file to Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to import csv file to Python. I have two question here.

**Q1.** my code is:

```
import csv
with open('highfrequency2.csv') as csvfile:
  freq=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  for row in freq:
    print(row[1],row[8])
```

But there is an error message here

**IndexError: list index out of range**

**Q2.** my data output looks like

```
['WOSl.TQ', '02-Jan-14', '51:48.0', 'Quote', '', '']
['WOSl.TQ', '02-Jan-14', '51:48.0', 'Quote', '', '']
['WOSl.TQ', '02-Jan-14', '51:48.0', 'Quote', '', '']
['WOSl.TQ', '02-Jan-14', '51:48.0', 'Quote', '', ''] 
['WOSl.TQ', '02-Jan-14', '51:48.0', 'Quote', '', '']
.....
....
```

Do I have to use 'r' or 'rb' function in reading the file ?

I want to see the 2nd and the 8th row of the CSV file.

Comment: The first thing I would do if it was me doing this problem is to run csvlint to make sure the csv file is correct.

Answer (score 2):

your row has 6 elements and you're trying to print the 2nd and the 9th.  well, the latter does not exist, hence list index out of range (indexing starts with 0).

Comment: Hi thanks very much. I think i made a stupid mistake. In excel, Row  means  horizontal line, but in Python Row means vertical line. Well, I just want to see the first several horizontal lines of csv data. Anything I could do about that ? Thanks again.

Comment: i believe freq is a list of lists? just go `for i in range(8): print freq[i]`?

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham, I see, I didn't verify my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want rows 2-8, use `itertools.islice` on the reader object:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice, izip

with open('highfrequency2.csv') as csvfile:
    freq = csv.reader(csvfile)
    # create islice object
    interest = islice(freq, 1, 8, None))
    # iterate over islice object getting row at a time
    for row in interest:
       print(row)
```

If you just want those two specific rows use a `step` of 6:

```
 import csv
from itertools import islice, izip

with open('highfrequency2.csv') as csvfile:
    freq = csv.reader(csvfile)
    interest = islice(freq, 1, 8, 6))
    for row in interest:
       print(row)
```

Or call next on the reader object after skipping the first line:

```
import csv

with open('highfrequency2.csv') as csvfile:
    freq = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(freq)
    # create generator expression
    interest = (next(freq) for _ in range(7))
    for row in interest:
       print(row)
```

Or using enumerate:

```
 import csv

with open('highfrequency2.csv') as csvfile:
    freq = csv.reader(csvfile)
    interest = (row for ind, row in enumerate(freq) if ind in {1,7})
    for row in interest:
       print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed Padraic. Just another quick one.

Comment: @TristanSun,  sure, what is the issue?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed Padraic. It works. Just another quick one. How can I generate the output in table format ? Just like my original table format. Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean to a csv file?

Comment: I used your code and the output came all together. I just want to see the output line by line. Is there any way to do this ? Like my original table. Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much. I used enumerate, but there is an error said: NameError: name 'csv' is not defined....

Comment: You need to import csv! I resumed you already had since you were using it.

Comment: I would also recommend using islice as it only iterates over the minimum amount of elements